# Combining all elements in a vector of lists based on the common first element of each list in the vector in R

Tags: r, list, vector, frequency, frequency-analysis

I have a fairly large vector of lists (about `300,000` rows). 
For example, let's consider the following:

```
vec = c( 
  list(c("A",10,11,12)), 
  list(c("B",10,11,15)),
  list(c("A",10,12,12,16)),
  list(c("A",11,12,16,17)) )
```

Now, I want to do the following:

For each unique first element of each list in the vector, I need all the unique elements occurring corresponding to this in all the lists in the vector, along with the respective frequencies.

Output would be somewhat like:

For `A`, I would have elements `10, 11 12, 16 & 17` with frequencies `2,2,4,2 & 1` respectively. For `B`, it would be `10, 11, 15` with frequencies `1,1,1`.

Many thanks in advance, 
Ankur.

Comment: (1) Please check your code's brackets; (2) You have a list of vectors, or a vector of vectors, but not a vector of lists; (3) What do you mean by 300,000 rows?; (4) Are you aware that if you combine character elements with numeric elements in an atomic vector, the entire vector will be coerced to character?; (5) Please try to clarify your post's title.

Comment: I've just edited because I'm assuming its a flat vector and there was a missing parenthesis. Please revert the edit if the vector is really nested more deeply. I've arranged the code to show the simple nesting.

Comment: (2) I have a vector of lists as defined by "vec". 
(3) Length of "vec" in my code is 300,000. However, here we can work with this short example.
(4) I'm aware of coercing. Let's assume that the entire vector is character.
@jbaums

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman . This is exactly what I meant.

Comment: there is no such thing as a vector of lists

Comment: @mtoto `is.vector(c(list(1,2,3),list(4,5,6)))` would like to disagree with you.

Comment: technically yes, can you tell me however the last time you referred to a `list` as a `vector`?  also: `str(c(list(1,2,3),list(4,5,6)))`

Comment: Yup, its a list **and** a vector, and what R calls it at any point is rather arbitrary. Have seen this discussion on R-help a few times.

Comment: A list is a vector - no need to argue that.. my point above was that the OP does not have a vector of lists, since his inner lists are coerced to atomic vectors.

Comment: `c(list(),list(),list())` looks like a vector of lists to me, and is what the OP has at the top level. `c("A",1,2,3)` is never going to be a vector of lists, if that's what you are talking about though (I think we are talking at cross-purposes here)

Comment: Yeah I think we got a bit off topic. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

First, a simpler way to create your list is:

```
L <- list(c("A", 10, 11, 12), 
          c("B", 10, 11, 15), 
          c("A", 10, 12, 12, 16), 
          c("A", 11, 12, 16, 17))
```

Now you can split by the first character, and then tabulate all but the first character.

```
tapply(L, sapply(L, '[[', 1), function(x) 
  table(unlist(lapply(x, function(x) x[-1]))))

## $A
## 
## 10 11 12 16 17 
##  2  2  4  2  1 
## 
## $B
## 
## 10 11 15 
##  1  1  1
```

---

Scaling up to a list comprising 300,000 elements of similar size:

```
L <- replicate(300000, c(sample(LETTERS, 1), sample(100, sample(3:4, 1))))

system.time(
  freqs <- tapply(L, sapply(L, '[[', 1), function(x) 
    table(unlist(lapply(x, function(x) x[-1]))))
)

## user  system elapsed 
## 0.68    0.00    0.69
```

---

If you want to sort the vectors of the resulting list, as per the OP's comment below, you can just modify the function applied to the groups of `L`:

```
tapply(L, sapply(L, '[[', 1), function(x) 
  sort(table(unlist(lapply(x, function(x) x[-1]))), decreasing=TRUE))

## $A
## 
## 12 10 11 16 17 
##  4  2  2  2  1 
## 
## $B
## 
## 10 11 15 
##  1  1  1
```

---

If you only want to tabulate the values for a particular group, e.g. group `A` (the vectors that begin with `A`), you can either subset the above result:

```
L2 <- tapply(L, sapply(L, '[[', 1), function(x) 
  sort(table(unlist(lapply(x, function(x) x[-1]))), decreasing=TRUE), 
  simplify=FALSE)

L2$A
```

(Note that I've added `simplify=FALSE` so that this will work even if the number of unique elements is the same across groups.)

It's more efficient to only perform the operation for the group of interest, though, in which case maybe the following is better:

```
sort(table(unlist(
  lapply(split(L, sapply(L, '[[', 1))$A, function(x) x[-1])
)), decreasing=TRUE)
```

where `split` first splits `L` into groups according to vectors' first element, and we then subset to just group `A` with `$A`.

Comment: Neat, my only worry about solutions like this might be the construction of long vectors from the 300,000 elements (which is then fed into `table`). It might be slower than an approach that loops and builds a table incrementally from the elements. Go on, scale the data up to 300,000 elements and see how long it takes! (answer: 3 seconds on a 300,000 length list with ~10 elements in each!)

Comment: Thanks @jbaums . What if I want to sort the inner lists based on decreasing order of frequencies?

Comment: @James1991 - do you mean sort the vectors of the resulting list? - see my edit.

Comment: Yes. So for "A", it would be:
12 10 11 16 17 with frequencies 4 2 2 2 1

@jbaums

Comment: Great! @jbaums.
One other aspect.
If I want to only want to get the resultant list for some values specified in a vector, then? 
For example, say i have a vector with "A" in it. Then I want only the $A in the output list.